# How, in a script, can I determine if a file is currently being written to by another process?

Tags: bash, openoffice.org, process

I'm very new to bash scripting, so I might be barking up the wrong tree, but here is my current situation:

In a script, I start **soffice**; to convert an **odt** to a **pdf**

It seems that *soffice* detaches itself from the script's process, and wanders off to do its own thing.. Okay, that's fine; GUI apps tend to do that ...

However I need to wait until the new *pdf* has been fully written, as my next step involves processing that new *pdf*.

(As far as I know) I can't utilize soffice's process-ID, because it may have already been a running process before my script started: eg. *soffice* may be already open for normal GUI activity for another unrelated document/presentation/spreadsheet.

The crux of the matter for me is that before I can proceed, the writing of the new *pdf* must be finalized...

Is there some way to determine when a file is **no longer** open to another process in "write" mode? ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `lsof | grep /absolute/path/to/file.txt` to see if a file is open.
If the file is open, this command will return status 0, otherwise it will return 256 (1).

Be aware that this command will take a second since there are, normally, a lot of files open at any time.

You can also use `lsof -c gedit`, for example, to see which file gedit has opened. Restricting the output to one process will reduce execution time to practically nought.

Here's a script to wait:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    if ! [[ `lsof -c python3.2 | grep test.py` ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    sleep 0.5
done
echo "done"
```

This runs while a process 'pyhton3.2' has got the file 'test.py' opened. As soon as the file is closed, it moves on to 'echo done' and exits.

I've put 'sleep 0.5' in there so that the loop doesn't hog the CPU all that badly. Otherwise, it will use 100% cpu.

**Bonus**
There seems to be an easy way to convent odt to pdf:

> Thanks to scls19fr on the OOo Forum
>   for this lovely tip. You can convert
>   OpenOffice Writer files to PDF from
>   the command line using `unoconv -f pdf
>   input.odt` To get unoconv, simply run
>   `sudo apt-get install unoconv` at the
>   terminal.
>   *(rhyshale of rhyshale.wordpress.com)*

Comment: Wrap this in an until loop and you've got a deal.

Comment: Done that. :-) I hope it's not terrible style - haven't bothered to read up on best practices. It works well anyway.

Comment: Thanks Stefano... yes, it does work... so it is a good and correct answer.. One a side note, it has highlighted that what is happening in soffice is **not** as I thought.. It seems that a temporary file is being created and the **final** file is (perhaps/probably) renamed upon completion... So I'm now looking at that... in which case, I may just need to wait for its **existance*...    ... and thanks for the link on unoconv .. I'll look into it.. (overall, I'm converting .pdf to multiple ..jpegs  one per page)

Comment: @fred.bear to wait until a file exists, replace the if-statement with this: `if [ -f test.odf ]`. (bash script can be so cryptic sometimes...)

Comment: try `lsof -- /path/to/file` instead to avoid the `grep`'ing

Comment: With a named pipe, lsof just hangs (waiting for stdin?)